# Why are float literals represented as are despite the error?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, literals

My understanding is that floats are internally represented as binary expansion, and that introduces errors. If that is the case, then why are float literals represented as are given? Suppose that `0.1` is represented internally as `0.0999999999999999` according to binary expansion (I am using a fake example, just to show the point. This particular value is probably not correct.). Then in inspection or in the return value of irb, why does it/why is it possible to print the given literal `0.1` and not `0.0999999999999999`? Isn't the original literal form gone once it is interpreted and expanded into binary?

In other words, a float literal-to-internal binary expression is a many-to-one mapping. Different float literals that are close enough are mapped to the same internal binary expression. Why then is it possible to reconstruct the original literal from the internal expression (modulo differences between `1.10` and `1.1`, `1.23e2` `123.0` as in Mark Dickinson's comment)?

Comment: Yeah, it's gone.  For some reason, though, people go to great lengths to *hide* the fact that it's gone.

Comment: The original literal isn't necessarily reconstructed.  A literal that rounds the same as the one you fed it is reconstructed.

Comment: @tmyklebu: True, but the key point here is that if you use round-to-nearest when going from decimal to binary, and a shortest-string based representation when going from binary to decimal, then any decimal literal with 15 or fewer significant digits (assuming IEEE 754 binary64, keeping away from underflow and overflow boundaries, etc.) *will* recover the same digits on roundtripping.  Of course, it won't necessarily be the exact same string ('1.10' will come out as '1.1'; '1.23e2' will come out as something like '123.0'), but its decimal value will be identical to that of the original literal.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Yes, but you needed quite the list of caveats in order to say something true.  (Importantly, not all floating-point numbers can be specified in decimal with only 15 significant digits; I need 16 in order to tell the difference between `2^52` and `2^52+1`.)

Comment: Mark Dickinson's comment recognizes my point exactly.

Comment: @sawa: You're asking why it's possible to convert from decimal to binary and back?  Or you're asking why Mark's comment is true?  Or what?

Comment: @tmyklebu: Right; that's going the other way, though.  For IEEE 754 binary64 format, `17` is the magic number for binary -> decimal -> binary roundtrips;  `15` is the magic number for decimal -> binary -> decimal roundtrips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby (like several other languages, including Java and Python) uses a "shortest-string" representation when converting  binary floating-point numbers to decimal for display purposes:  given a binary floating-point number, it will compute the shortest decimal string that rounds *back* to that binary floating-point number under the usual round-to-nearest decimal-to-binary method.

Now suppose that we start out with a *reasonably short* (in terms of number of significant digits) decimal literal, `123.456` for example, and convert that to the nearest binary float, `z`.  Clearly `123.456` is *one* decimal string that rounds to `z`, so it's a candidate for the representation of `z`, and it should be at least plausible that the "shortest-string" algorithm will spit that back at us.  But we'd like more than just plausibility here: to be sure that `123.456` is exactly what we're going to get back, all we need to know is that there aren't any other, shorter, candidates.

And that's true, essentially because if we restrict to short-ish decimal values (to be made more precise below), the spacing between successive such values is larger than the spacing between successive floats.  More precisely, we can make a statement like the following:

> Any decimal literal `x` with 15 or fewer significant digits and absolute value
>   between `10^-307` and `10^308` will be recovered by the "shortest-string" algorithm.

Here by "recovered", I mean that the output string will have the same decimal digits, and the same value as the original literal when thought of as a decimal number;  it's still possible that the form of the literal may have changed, e.g., from `1.230` to `1.23`, or from `0.000345` to `3.45e-4`.  I'm also assuming IEEE 754 binary64 format with the usual round-ties-to-even rounding mode.

Now let's give a sketch of a proof.  Without loss of generality, assume `x` is positive.  Let `z` be the binary floating-point value nearest `x`.  We have to show that there's no other, shorter, string `y` that *also* rounds to `z` under round-to-nearest.  But if `y` is a shorter string than `x`, it's also representable in 15 significant digits or fewer, so it differs from `x` by at least one 'unit in the last place'.  To formalize that, find integers `e` and `f` such that `2^(e-1) <= x < 2^e` and `10^(f-1) < x <= 10^f`. Then the difference `|x-y|` is at least `10^(f-15)`.  However, if `y` is too far away from `x`, it can't possibly round to `z`: since the binary64 format has a precision of 53 bits (away from the underflow and overflow ranges, at least) the interval of numbers that round to `z` has width at most `2^(e-53)`<sup>[1]</sup>.  We need to show that the width of this interval is smaller than `|x-y|`; that is, that `2^(e-53) < 10^(f-15)`.

But this follows from our choices: `2^(e-53) <= 2^-52 x` by our choice of `e`, and since `2^-52 < 10^-15` we get `2^(e-53) < 10^-15 x`.  Then `10^-15 x <= 10^(f-15)` (by choice of `f`).

It's not hard to find examples showing that `15` is best possible here.  For example, the literal `8.123451234512346` has 16 significant digits, and converts to the floating-point value `0x1.03f35000dc341p+3`, or `4573096494089025/562949953421312`.  When rendered back as a string using the shortest string algorithm, we get `8.123451234512347`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Not quite true: there's an annoying corner case when `z` is an exact power of two, in which case the width of the interval is `1.5 2^(e-53)`.  The statement remains true in that case, though;  I'll leave the details as an exercise.

Comment: Hmm.  This proof isn't as clean as I'd like.  The underlying idea is straightforward: going from 15-digit decimal to 53-bit binary and back roundtrips (essentially because 10^15 < 2^52), so the decimal-to-binary part is injective.  Given that injectivity, there can only ever be at most one "shortest string" candidate with 15 digits or fewer for any particular given binary float, so if we started from a 15-digit string in the first place, the "shortest string" algorithm recovers it.  I may try to find time to rewrite the proof at some point.

Answer (score 6):

The decimal-to-floating-point conversion applied to floating-point literals such as “0.1” rounds to the nearest floating-point (0.5 [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)) for most platforms. (Ruby calls a function from the platform for this, and the only fallback Ruby's source code [contains](https://github.com/replit/emscripted-ruby/blob/master/ruby-1.8.7/missing/strtod.c) for portability is awful, but let us assume conversion to the nearest). As a consequence, if you print to any number of decimals between 1…15 the closest decimal representation to the double that correspond to the literal `0.1`, then the result is 0.10…0 (and the trailing zeroes can be omitted, of course), and if you print the shortest decimal representation that converts back to the double nearest 0.1, then this results in “0.1”, of course.

Programming languages usually use one of the above two approaches (fixed number of significant digits, or shortest decimal representation that converts back to the original floating-point number) when converting floating-point number to a decimal representation. Ruby uses the latter.

[This article](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf) introduced “floating-point to shortest decimal representation that converts back to the same floating-point number” floating-point-to-decimal conversion.

Comment: It looks as though current Ruby does use David Gay's code: see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/util.c, though that may be new since Ruby 1.9.  (I haven't been following.)  So with any luck the 'awful' fallback you referred to isn't in use any more.

Comment: @MarkDickinson David Gay's implementation is not “naive to the point of being portable” like the naive one I linked to, so perhaps mine is used as a fallback's fallback. Gay's implementation can go more horribly wrong than the naive implementation when used in the wrong conditions (e.g. PHP fiasco), so that would make sense.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I would investigate but my week-end is booked for computing the double-precision values of `x` that make the double-precision equality `x + a == b` true using only double-precision computations. It is really easy and involves few special cases with rationals or higher precision floating-point, but the higher precision appears to be crucial to the simplicity (sniped?).

Comment: Yes, possibly a fallback fallback.  I bet @RickRegan would know for sure. :-)